# How can I dynamically set the top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can I dynamically set the top position of the sortable drag area of each dragged element

js

```
$( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '#textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><div class="option_toolbar"><div class="draggable-area dr-toolbar">Drag</div></div><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();

      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable({
    handle: ".draggable-area",
  });
```

CSS

```
#editorDesignView:hover .option_toolbar {
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
     left: 68%; 
    top: 1;
}
```

For more info please visit on my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/otoj7rak/3/)

Comment: Do you mean you want the element to be inserted wherever it is dropped?

Comment: @Terry please check out the fiddle drag n drop 10 or 15 time and then hover the dropped element there will the drag will appear try to sort the elements u will understand what I mean

Comment: Still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You don't want the drag handler to show? Or something else?

Comment: @Terry the problem is when the items are more than the window height then the drag handler does not work properly ( suppose if I have drag n drop 20 items the scroll bar has appear and if I scroll down and try to sort the element it does not work properly ) I think it is because top css property

Comment: Why not just use Draggable and Sortable?

Comment: @Twisty I am making the handler because I am also editing the content and for that I am using contenteditable="true"